# Java - track how many object has referenced by other object

Tags: java

I have to keep track of how many objects have been referenced by another object , let's say I have a class moon that refer to a planet class :

```
private String moonName;
private planet planet;

public bulan(String moonName, planet planet) {
    this.moonName = moonName;
    this.planet = planet;
    planet.addMoon(moonName);
}
```

then i create moon object in test class :

```
moon Luna = new moon("Luna",Earth);
```

i want class planet to "know" that planet class has referenced by moon class, how to do that?

Comment: Use the correct camelcase naming convention in your code, e.g. `Moon luna = new Moon("Luna", earth);`

Comment: Do you mean that `Planet` has `Moon` and `Moon` has `Planet`

Comment: Why do you want that? Seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: Post code for your Planet and Moon class. From current content, it's not very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started:

```
class Moon{
    public final String name;
    public final Planet planet;
    public Moon(String name, Planet planet) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.planet = planet;
    }
}

class Planet{
    public final String name;
    private List<Moon> moons = new ArrayList<>();
    public Planet(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void addMoon(Moon moon){
        this.moons.add(moon);
    }
    public List<Moon> getMoons(){
        return this.moons;
    }
}
```

Also read what Stephen Ngo wrote about general points. You maybe should read up on naming conventions in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Quite new to StackOverflow, but I think I can be of assistance.

**Some general pointers before I hit the main point:**

- "Planet" is an **Entity**, so you have to write 
  `private Planet planet` **not** `private planet planet`
- Apply that same concept to your Moon, Planet (e.g `Moon moon = new Moon("Luna, Earth")`
- If your code above is class **Moon**, then your constructor should have the same name as your class (e.g `public Moon(String moonName, Planet planet){}`)

**Now to the main point:**

Now because everytime your constructor is called, it **initializes** the Planet reference object, my suggestion is to simply include an **instance variable** (Which lives until the end of the session), **a counter**, and a **getter method**.
For example:

```
private int numCalled = 0;
    public Moon(String moonName, Planet planet){ 
      this.moonName;
      this.planet=planet;
      planet.addMoon(moonName);
      numCalled++;
    }
    public int getNumCalled(){
        return numCalled;
    }
```

Comment: I suppose you meant `return numCalled` on the last line and not call a method named `numCalled`. You should correct that